# Opencart adding and duplicating error

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce, opencart2.x

I tried adding new product or duplicating product but it gives me the following errors:

```
Notice: Error: Duplicate entry '109-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
Error No: 1062
INSERT INTO oc_product_description SET product_id = '109',
...
Error No: 1062
INSERT INTO oc_product_to_store SET product_id = '109', store_id = '0' in....
```

The issue seems to be related to `oc_product_description`. I've tried to check the Auto Increment box and save, but it gave me "Query error 1063":

[image: Query error: #1063 Incorrect column specifier for column 'description']

Comment: Why would you insert a primary key? You always leave it blank man.

Comment: How do i fix this issue? or change the primary key? please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the attribute `auto_increment` from product_id in `oc_product_description`. The `product_id` is acting as `foreign key` in `oc_product_description`. Once you remove `auto_increment` from `product_id`, it will work just fine.

Comment: hey Ali, i've removed the auto_increment, it worked a few products and now i am getting this error again Notice: Error: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
Error No: 1062
 Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Notices are fine. You can turn `display errors` off in store settings.

Comment: I've tried that also, these are the exact errors: Notice: Error: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
Error No: 1062
INSERT INTO oc_product SET model, INSERT INTO oc_product_to_store SET product_id, INSERT INTO oc_product_to_category SET product_id, Error: Duplicate entry '0-0' for key 'PRIMARY'.... Now should i go into each one and delete the auto_increment?

Comment: add me on skype. `Syed Ali Zia` let me help you.